# Combine values in column week (i.e. week 1, week 2, etc) into week range (week 1-2 or week 1, 2)?

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, sum, case

General SQL question using online SQLite editor, if I have the following table:

| item | week | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | 1 | 35 |
| item2 | 1 | 25 |
| item3 | 1 | 24 |
| item1 | 2 | 35 |
| item2 | 2 | 34 |
| item1 | 3 | 24 |
| item2 | 3 | 45 |
| item1 | 4 | 44 |
| item2 | 4 | 51 |
| item1 | 5 | 1 |
| item3 | 5 | 100 |

how would I get the output to be this:

| item | weeks | total_sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | 1-2 | 70 |
| item2 | 3-4 | 96 |
| item3 | 5 | 100 |

More specifically, how would I (if possible) show the week as a range ('***week 1-2***' or even '***week 1, 2***') rather than just '***week 1***', where the range would be the week(s) that the item had the most sales for each week?

Some code I have been working on is as follows:

```
SELECT item, 
    SUM(sales) OVER (
          PARTITION BY week order by item) AS total_sales
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY item;
```

The above code gets me the sum or total sales for the week, but I am completely lost as to how one would get the week as a range.

Any help or clarification is appreciated. [Example code](https://anotepad.com/notes/dwxex9gn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression to create the ranges and group by that expression and `item`:

```
SELECT item,
       CASE 
         WHEN week <= 2 THEN '1-2'
         WHEN week <= 4 THEN '3-4'
         WHEN week <= 5 THEN '5'
         ELSE '>5'
       END weeks,
       SUM(sales) total_sales
FROM table1
GROUP BY item, weeks;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=89e62473b60b2013ab050aa7d0961dd8).

Comment: Ah I didn't even think about CASE. To expand on this as I am curious, your solution ends up having all items with "1-2". If I wanted to have the week/range show up specifically for the week(s) that the item had the most sales out of all, how would one do that? So like ice cream would have weeks 1-2, cookies weeks 3-4 and cupcake week 5

Comment: @Krasnips questions are not asked in the comments section. This is a different requirement for which you should ask a new question.

Comment: Yes understood. I asked in a new question. I am just curious as to how one goes about solving this so I appreciate your help!