# Get week range (week 1-2 or week 1, 2) for each week where item has the most sales out of items list

Tags: sql, sqlite

Building off a general SQL question I already asked using online SQLite editor [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72033964/sql-how-to-combine-values-in-column-week-i-e-week-1-week-2-etc-into-week-r), if I have the following table:

| item | week | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | 1 | 35 |
| item2 | 1 | 25 |
| item3 | 1 | 24 |
| item1 | 2 | 35 |
| item2 | 2 | 34 |
| item1 | 3 | 24 |
| item2 | 3 | 45 |
| item1 | 4 | 44 |
| item2 | 4 | 51 |
| item1 | 5 | 1 |
| item3 | 5 | 100 |

how would I get the output to be this:

| item | weeks | total_sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | 1-2 | 70 |
| item2 | 3-4 | 96 |
| item3 | 5 | 100 |

In the table directly above, weeks 1-2 are assigned to item1 since the total sales for that time period were highest for item1. Same with weeks 3-4, assigned to item2 since that item's total sales were the highest for that time period.

Some code I have been working on is as follows:

```
SELECT item, 
    SUM(sales) OVER (
          PARTITION BY week order by item) AS total_sales
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY item;
```

CASE was suggested to get the "range" for week the item sold the most out of all items, but this populates the items with the same week range. With case added, code is this:

```
SELECT item,
       CASE 
         WHEN week <= 2 THEN '1-2'
         WHEN week <= 4 THEN '3-4'
         WHEN week <= 5 THEN '5'
         ELSE '>5'
       END weeks,
       SUM(sales) OVER(partition by week order by item) as total_sales
FROM table1
GROUP BY item;
```

Here is a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=967396929449febe0d9f6e9afd10fa6a)

The above code outputs something similar to:

| item | weeks | total_sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | 1-2 | 70 |
| item2 | 1-2 | 96 |
| item3 | 1-2 | 100 |

which is wrong as only item1 was the top seller during weeks 1-2.

I really am not sure how one would get the week(s) for an item when it was the top seller. Again, item1 would have just ***"Week 1-2"*** populated once, item2 would have just ***"Week 3-4"*** populated once as those were their highest selling weeks.

Everything else I have done just fine. Any guidance or help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you just add a row_number() function to implement your business logic and then pick the rows where the row_number() = 1.

here is the fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oWBDK3xTSgiCMaw7MS5XKm/0

and here is the fiddle with your demo data  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=62450660190d7f161f5790d188736260

```
with t as (
SELECT item,
       CASE 
         WHEN week <= 2 THEN '1-2'
         WHEN week <= 4 THEN '3-4'
         WHEN week <= 5 THEN '5'
         ELSE '>5'
       END weeks,
       SUM(sales) as total_sales
FROM table1
GROUP BY item, 
  CASE 
         WHEN week <= 2 THEN '1-2'
         WHEN week <= 4 THEN '3-4'
         WHEN week <= 5 THEN '5'
         ELSE '>5'
       END ),
  t2 as (
  select item, weeks, total_sales,
  row_number() over (partition by weeks order by total_sales desc) rn  from t)
  select * from t2 where rn = 1 order by weeks
```

Answer (score 2):

You need 2 levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT item, weeks, MAX(total_sales) total_sales
FROM (
  SELECT item,
         CASE 
           WHEN week <= 2 THEN '1-2'
           WHEN week <= 4 THEN '3-4'
           WHEN week <= 5 THEN '5'
           ELSE '>5'
         END weeks,
         SUM(sales) total_sales
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY item, weeks
)
GROUP BY weeks;
```

The outer query uses SQLite's feature of [Bare columns in an aggregate query](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bare_columns_in_an_aggregate_query) and returns the row with the max value of `total_sales`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=05aa8ab61459a96689220a7dbba8222c).

Comment: think there might be something a bit off with this. Not seeing week 3-4 and some totals might be off

Comment: @BryanDellinger you are right. It seems I misread the requirement. The query returned all items and the week range with the most sales for each item. I edited to return all week ranges with the item most sold.